# SWT StyledText text completion ability

Tags: swt, jface, styledtext

Is there a way to add ability like code completion in eclipse to StyledText widget. I have a list of possible string inserts which depend on previous text.

Comment: Is this just SWT? SWT + JFace? An eclipse plugin? An eclipse text editor?

Comment: SWT + JFace and org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText

Comment: Look at using the JFace `TextViewer` and `ContentAssistant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) were right. I found very useful example [SWT Completion Editor](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTCompletionEditor.htm)